# BDD C# error when i run feature does not contain a definition for 'keyword'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

I am trying out BBD using Specflow.  I am getting an error when I run the feature file.
The error is:

```
Result Message: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'keyword'
```

The error is somewhere in this method:

```
 [Then(@"I should see the result for keyword")]
    public void ThenIShouldSeeTheResultForeyword(Table table)
    {
        dynamic tableDetail = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
        String key = tableDetail.keyword;
        if (currentDriver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(key)).Displayed == true)
            Console.WriteLine("Control Exist");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Control not exist");
    }
```

My feature file implementation is:

```
@SmokeTest
@Browser:Chrome
Scenario: Google Search for Execute Automation
    Given I have navigated to Google page
    Given I see the Google page fully loaded
    When I type search keyword as
    | Keyword     |      
    | Formula One |
    Then I should see the result for keyword
    | keyword     |       
    | Formula One |


My steps defincition file implementation is:

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using System.Configuration;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
    using Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit.Bindings;
    using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;
    using SpecFlow.Assist;
    using SpecFlow;

    namespace SpecFlowFirst.Steps
    {
        [Binding]
        class GoogleSearchSteps
        {
            IWebDriver currentDriver = null;

            [Given(@"I have navigated to Google page")]
            public void GivenIhaveNavigatedToGooglePage()
            {
                Browser.Current.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["seleniumBaseURL"]);
                currentDriver = Browser.Current;
            }

            [Given(@"I see the Google page fully loaded")]
            public void GivenISeeTheGooglePageFullyLoaded()
            {
                if (currentDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Displayed == true)
                    Console.WriteLine("Page loaded fully");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Page failed to load");
            }

            [When(@"I type search keyword as")]
            public void WhenITypSsearchKeywordAs(Table table)
            {
                dynamic tableDetail = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
                currentDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys(tableDetail.keyword);
            }

            [Then(@"I should see the result for keyword")]
            public void ThenIShouldSeeTheResultForeyword(Table table)
            {
                dynamic tableDetail = table.CreateDynamicInstance();
                String key = tableDetail.keyword;
                if (currentDriver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(key)).Displayed == true)
                    Console.WriteLine("Control Exist");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Control not exist");
            }
            }


    }
```

I am not sure why the error is being thrown when I run the feature.  The solution builds without errors.

The full error trace is:

```
  Test Name:    GoogleSearchForExecuteAutomation on Chrome
Test FullName:  SpecFlowFirst.Features.GoogleSearchFeature.GoogleSearchForExecuteAutomation on Chrome
Test Source:    e:\RL Fusion\projects\BDD\C# BDD\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\Features\GoogleSearch.feature : line 20
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:11.715

Result Message: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'keyword'
Result StackTrace:  
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
at SpecFlowFirst.Steps.GoogleSearchSteps.WhenITypSsearchKeywordAs(Table table) in e:\RL Fusion\projects\BDD\C# BDD\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\Steps\GoogleSearchSteps.cs:line 42
at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager , Table )
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
at SpecFlowFirst.Features.GoogleSearchFeature.ScenarioCleanup() in e:\RL Fusion\projects\BDD\C# BDD\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\Features\GoogleSearch.feature.cs:line 0
at SpecFlowFirst.Features.GoogleSearchFeature.GoogleSearchForExecuteAutomation(String browser) in e:\RL Fusion\projects\BDD\C# BDD\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\SpecFlowFirst\Features\GoogleSearch.feature:line 26
```

Thanks for help, Riaz

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using? From where do you get the CreateDynamicInstance method? I do not find it in the SpecFlow source.

Comment: @AndreasWillich its from [this project](https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/wiki/Table-to-dynamic-set)

Comment: Ok, then the error is in this package according to the error.

Comment: I have the following specflow packages SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic, specFlow.Assist; SpecFlow; SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic;  I am using SpecFlow 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

briefly looking at the [code for that method](https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/blob/master/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/DynamicTableHelpers.cs) I think it might be 'fixing' the case of the property, so try using `String key = tableDetail.Keyword`

Comment: I've tried that.  I still get the same error. Result Message: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'keyword

Answer (score 0):

[I rewrote Baseclass.Contrib.SpecFlow.Selenium.NUnit for 2.1 support.](https://github.com/unickq/unickq.seleniumHelper)

New codebase, @ignore tag support for nunit3 and several testing services like BrowserStack, SauceLabs, TestingBot. Just in case you want to upgrade to 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the scenario in question:

> ```
> Scenario: Google Search for Execute Automation
>     Given I have navigated to Google page
>     Given I see the Google page fully loaded
>     When I type search keyword as
>     | Keyword     |      
>     | Formula One |
>     Then I should see the result for keyword
>     | keyword     |       
>     | Formula One |
> ```

I just want to point out that:

- Your `when`statement has a table with a `Keyword` column (with an upper case K),
- And your `then` statement has a table with a `keyword` column (with a lower case k).

This means if you update both usages of `tableDetails.Keyword` at the same time (from `keyword` to `Keyword`, or vice versa), one of them will always throw.

---

### Debugging advice

If this doesn't work for you, keep in mind that [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IDictionary<string, object>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`, which means you can always print to the console the available keys to understand what is actually being created by `CreateDynamicInstance`